# Can Android devices used as iBeacon emitter?

Tags: android, ibeacon

I'm trying to write a game plan and I need information of this question :

**Can Android devices used as iBeacon emitters like iOS devices?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Bluetooth LE support in Android 4.3 and 4.4 only supports the “central” role, meaning it can act as a device that consumes Bluetooth LE data. The “peripheral” role, which is used by devices being the Bluetooth LE data provider, is not supported. This keeps Android devices from acting as an iBeacon, because iBeacons are nothing more than Bluetooth LE peripheral mode advertisers. And if a device can’t advertise, it can’t act as an iBeacon.

For more information see [Why Android Devices Can’t Act as iBeacons](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/12/15/why-android-devices-cant-act-as-ibeacons.html).

Answer (score -3):

> iBeacon is an indoor positioning system that Apple Inc. calls
>   "a new class of low-powered, low-cost transmitters that can notify
>   nearby iOS 7 devices of their presence." They can also be used by
>   the **Android operating system**.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBeacon)

Comment: Yes Android devices can see messages emitted by iBeacon devices, but my question is, can Android devices emit messages under BLE standard?